# Question of batch file with IF exists/ not exists in cmd

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make a script, but the problem was encountered during the project.

According to the following script, if all the files are exist, then will run the copy function.
--> This is ok.

However, if one of file or more than one files are not exist, then how to list out all the error messages first, then pause it and run the copy function.

Many thanks.

**Code**

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "G:\A.TXT" (

IF EXIST "G:\B.TXT" (

IF EXIST "G:\C.TXT" (

    CALL :COPY

) ) )


IF NOT EXIST "G:\A.TXT" (

    CALL :A

IF NOT EXIST "G:\A.TXT" (

    CALL :B

IF NOT EXIST "G:\A.TXT" (

    CALL :C

) ) )

:A

CLS

CALL :HEADER

    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: A File Missed!' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.

PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:B

CLS

CALL :HEADER

    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: B File Missed!' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.

PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:C

CLS

CALL :HEADER

    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: C File Missed!' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.

PAUSE

GOTO :EOF

:COPY

CLS

CALL :HEADER

    ECHO Copying Files...
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    ECHO.
    
    COPY G:\A.TXT H:\A.TXT
    
    COPY G:\B.TXT H:\B.TXT

    COPY G:\C.TXT H:\C.TXT

    ECHO.
    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Copy Completed!' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL

GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really overcomplicated things for yourself.

Using Conditional Operators:

```
@echo off
set "files="G:\A.txt" "G:\B.txt" "G:\C.txt""
for %%i in (%files%) do copy "%%~i" "H:\%%~i">nul 2>&1 && Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Copied %%i' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN" || Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: %%i File Missing!' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
```

or `if exist` and `else` statement.

```
@echo off
set "files="G:\A.txt" "G:\B.txt" "G:\C.txt""
for %%i in (%files%) do if exist "%%~i" (
    copy "%%~i" "H:\%%~i">nul 2>&1 && Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Copied %%i' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor GREEN"
   ) else (
    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'WARNING: %%i File Missing!' -BackGroundColor BLACK -ForegroundColor YELLOW"
)
```